# cloud-init error apt-get lock during boot

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I have the following issue running `cloud-init`

```
ip-10-211-207-121 login: [   28.947931] cloud-init[1220]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'modules:config' at Tue, 30 Jan 2018 15:48:57 +0000. Up 22.17 seconds.
[   52.606593] cloud-init[1917]: Hit:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
[   52.616075] cloud-init[1917]: Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
[   52.621917] cloud-init[1917]: Get:3 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
[   52.758989] cloud-init[1917]: Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
[   52.985058] cloud-init[1917]: Ign:5 http://pkg.ci.collectd.org/deb trusty InRelease
[   53.121861] cloud-init[1917]: Get:6 http://pkg.ci.collectd.org/deb trusty Release [14.6 kB]
[   53.191618] cloud-init[1917]: Get:7 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources [291 kB]
[   53.246856] cloud-init[1917]: Get:8 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources [2,524 B]
[   53.258281] cloud-init[1917]: Get:9 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources [189 kB]
[   53.270040] cloud-init[1917]: Get:10 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Sources [7,972 B]
[   53.281092] cloud-init[1917]: Get:11 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [709 kB]
[   53.319542] cloud-init[1917]: Get:12 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [294 kB]
[   53.333740] cloud-init[1917]: Get:13 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,560 B]
[   53.343177] cloud-init[1917]: Get:14 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,272 B]
[   53.353689] cloud-init[1917]: Get:15 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [580 kB]
[   53.368355] cloud-init[1917]: Get:16 http://pkg.ci.collectd.org/deb trusty Release.gpg [819 B]
[   54.330852] cloud-init[1917]: Get:17 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [234 kB]
[   54.341774] cloud-init[1917]: Get:18 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.2 kB]
[   54.355939] cloud-init[1917]: Get:19 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [8,052 B]
[   54.379123] cloud-init[1917]: Get:20 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Sources [3,436 B]
[   54.395653] cloud-init[1917]: Get:21 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Sources [4,908 B]
[   54.424343] cloud-init[1917]: Get:22 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [4,840 B]
[   54.447970] cloud-init[1917]: Get:23 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [6,612 B]
[   54.474048] cloud-init[1917]: Get:24 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [3,768 B]
[   54.819851] cloud-init[1917]: Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources [107 kB]
[   55.196540] cloud-init[1917]: Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources [2,116 B]
[   55.207513] cloud-init[1917]: Get:27 http://pkg.ci.collectd.org/deb trusty/collectd-5.7 amd64 Packages [5,327 B]
[   55.289297] cloud-init[1917]: Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources [49.3 kB]
[   55.316948] cloud-init[1917]: Get:29 https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt xenial InRelease [3,156 B]
[   55.398244] cloud-init[1917]: Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Sources [1,520 B]
[   55.489024] cloud-init[1917]: Get:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [435 kB]
[   55.565884] cloud-init[1917]: Get:32 https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,594 B]
[   55.844647] cloud-init[1917]: Get:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [189 kB]
[   56.038779] cloud-init[1917]: Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [7,224 B]
[   56.138713] cloud-init[1917]: Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [2,152 B]
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI event daemon.
[   56.224579] cloud-init[1917]: Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [200 kB]
[   56.426848] cloud-init[1917]: Get:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [102 kB]
[   56.605795] cloud-init[1917]: Get:38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,208 B]
[   56.701283] cloud-init[1917]: Get:39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,408 B]
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped New Relic Infrastructure Agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started New Relic Infrastructure Agent.
[   69.776262] cloud-init[1917]: Fetched 3,797 kB in 4s (915 kB/s)
[   73.386062] cloud-init[1917]: Reading package lists...
[   73.605684] cloud-init[1917]: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
[   73.616820] cloud-init[1917]: E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
[   73.622886] cloud-init[1917]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'modules:final' at Tue, 30 Jan 2018 15:49:26 +0000. Up 50.67 seconds.
[   73.628548] cloud-init[1917]: 2018-01-30 15:49:49,728 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed to install packages: ['devscripts', 'debhelper', 'build-essential', 'dh-make', 'chrony']
[   73.645252] cloud-init[1917]: 2018-01-30 15:49:49,762 - cc_package_update_upgrade_install.py[WARNING]: 1 failed with exceptions, re-raising the last one
[   73.651402] cloud-init[1917]: 2018-01-30 15:49:49,762 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module package-update-upgrade-install (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_package_update_upgrade_install' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_package_update_upgrade_install.py'>) failed
```

I've defined in my `cloud-init` file the following section:

```
packages:
  - devscripts
  - debhelper
  - build-essential
  - dh-make
  - chrony
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is this not essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525946/1695906?

Comment: Yes. There was an error in posting because stack overflow API were flaky at that time

Comment: There is a bug related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1693361

This is happening to me in AWS and not in LXD. I'm wondering if this is happening to you also in AWS.